# Can not change `ScheduleToStartTimeout `in cadence v0.11

Tags: cadence-workflow, cadence

I'm using cadence v0.11.
It failed to change `ScheduleToStartTimeout` in cadence v0.11.

[image: bad-case-schedule-start-timeout]

How to config `ScheduleToStartTimeout` take effect? Is it a bug for cadence 0.11?

Here is the minimum bad case which is used to reproduce this bug:
https://github.com/ahuigo/cadence-v11-bad-case

Comment: It’s very likely a bug. Can you try running the client version with later server to confirm if the bug is on server or client?

Comment: I can't try later version on server and client. It is too hard to upgrade.

BTW, I can confirm that there is no problem with the latest version on server and client.